# How to disable right click for Draw mode?

Tags: openlayers

I use draw mode:

```
  this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type,
      stopClick: true,
    });
```

When user makes right click in this mode it draws a new line. How to prevent it exception right map click?

I have tried to use condition, but it prevent all clicks:

```
condition: (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
      },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a condition which restricts drawing to the left button:

```
  this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type,
      stopClick: true,
      condition: (e) => noModifierKeys(e) && primaryAction(e),
    })
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-5m29q2?file=/main.js;